# Will Allah give me reward for sharing Quran recitation

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

If I share Quran recitation using social media and people hear it,will get reward for it?

Comment: If you do any good deed according to Sunnah and Quran to please Allah then you will be rewarded inshallah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions are judged according to a persons intention, so if you share Quran recitations with the intention of others benefiting from it, then you will be rewarded.
*"The deeds are considered by the intentions, and a person will get the reward according to his intention..."* [Bukhari, Muslim]
This applies to any act that is normally considered *mubah* (permissible), if it is done with a good intention you will get reward for it.